# Chrome extensions communication with Arduino

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, arduino, arduino-yun

My idea is to have an arduino board that will communicate with the browser.

- I want the arduino board to react (eg. blink led) when user is connected to a certain website.
- User inputs on the board ( eg. press button) will affect the browser (eg. close tab, switch tab).

I started learning and creating simple examples using chrome extensions tutorial.
However, since I am not myself a skilled programmer, I'd like to know if it is possible to achieve those things aforementioned.

How I imagine it right now it will be:

- Chrome extension writes into a json. Arduino reads data from json -> blink led.
- Arduino writes values in json. Chrome extension can automatically see changes in the file and react accordingly -> close tab( so, without having a user re-installing each time the extension).

Are this scenarios possible? Which would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: I think Web Bluetooth is a right method. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LV1Fk5ZXwA

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look at [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). That's a really easy real-time database with a lot of good tutorials (even some by Google).

Then you should use a library like [this one](https://github.com/googlesamples/firebase-arduino) on your Arduino.
(there are some [examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/firebase-arduino/blob/master/examples/FirebasePush_ESP8266/FirebasePush_ESP8266.ino) to look at)
And in your [chrome extension](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-06-power-your-chrome-extension-with-firebase.html) you can fetch the values from the database really easy again.